# Did NASA use metric units for the Mercury missions?

Tags: nasa, terminology, project-mercury, unit-systems

Did NASA use metric or English units for Project Mercury?

For example, did they measure delta-v in meters/second or in feet/second?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Project Mercury used [imperial units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) of measure. For example, the [Mercury spacecraft main instrument panel](http://history.nasa.gov/diagrams/mercury2.gif) indicated altitude in `FT` (feet):

[image: the Mercury spacecraft main instrument panel]

<sup>The Mercury spacecraft main instrument panel from Project Mercury Indoctrination, May 1959 (Source: [NASA](http://history.nasa.gov/diagrams/mercury.html). Click for full size)</sup>

They used [statute miles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile#Statute_mile) as a measure of distance in schematics, diagrams and other vectors in the documentation, for example this [Proceedings of a Conference on Results of the first U.S. manned suborbital space flight](http://msquair.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/results-of-the-first-manned-sub-orbital-space-flight.pdf) from June 6, 1961:

[image: First U.S. manned suborbital space flight - pictorial presentation of the overall flight]

<sup>First U.S. manned suborbital space flight - pictorial presentation of the overall flight (Source: [Public archive (in PDF format)](http://msquair.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/results-of-the-first-manned-sub-orbital-space-flight.pdf))</sup>

And even went at length to provide their personnel travelling abroad (in this case Mexico) with unit conversion tables from the imperial to the metric system of units in NASA's [Introduction to project Mercury and site handbook](http://www.scribd.com/doc/46186817/Introduction-to-Project-Mercury-And-Tracking-Sites-Handbook):

[image: Chapter 6, Page 13 extract from the Introduction to project Mercury and site handbook]

<sup>Page extract from the Introduction to project Mercury and site handbook, notes on personnel travels to Mexico (metric system of units)</sup>

Imperial units of measure persisted throughout the Mercury program. This is the mission timeline for the [Mercury-Redstone 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_4), launched on July 21, 1961:

```
T+ Time     Event                Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T+00:00:00  Liftoff              Mercury-Redstone lifts off, onboard clock starts.
T+00:00:16  Pitch Program        Redstone pitches over 2 deg/s from 90 deg to 45 deg.
T+00:00:40  End Pitch Program    Redstone reaches 45 deg pitch.
T+00:01:24  Max Q                Maximum dynamic pressure ~575 lbf/ft² (28 kPa).
T+00:02:20  BECO                 Redstone engine shutdown - Booster Engine Cutoff.
                                 Velocity 5,200 mph (2.3 km/s)
T+00:02:22  Tower Jettison       Escape Tower Jettison, no longer needed.
T+00:02:24  Craft Separation     Posigrade rockets fire for 1 s giving 15 ft/s (4.6 
                                 m/s) separation.
T+00:02:35  Turnaround Maneuver  Spacecraft (ASCS Automatic Stabilization and Control
                                 System) system rotates spacecraft 180 deg, to heat 
                                 shield forward attitude. Nose is pitched down 34 deg 
                                 to retro fire position.
T+00:05:00  Apogee               Apogee of about 115 mi (185 km) reached at 150 mi (240 
                                 km) downrange from launch site.
T+00:05:15  Retrofire            Three retro rockets fire for 10 s each. They are 
                                 started at 5 s intervals, firing overlaps. Delta-V of
                                 550 ft/s (170 m/s) is taken off forward velocity.
T+00:05:45  Retract Periscope    Periscope is automatically retracted in preparation 
                                 for reentry.
T+00:06:15  Retro Pack Jettison  One minute after retrofire retro pack is jettisoned,
                                 leaving heat shield clear.
T+00:06:20  Retro Attitude Man.  (ASCS) orients spacecraft in 34 deg nose down pitch, 0
                                 deg roll, 0 deg yaw.
T+00:07:15  .05 g Maneuver       (ASCS) detects beginning of reentry and rolls 
                                 spacecraft at 10 deg/s to stabilize spacecraft during 
                                 reentry.
T+00:09:38  Drogue Para. Deploy  Drogue parachute deployed at 22,000 ft (6.7 km) 
                                 slowing descent to 365 ft/s (111 m/s) and stabilizing 
                                 spacecraft.
T+00:09:45  Snorkel Deploy       Fresh air snorkel deploys at 20,000 ft (6.1 km). (ECS) 
                                 switches to emergency oxygen rate to cool cabin.
T+00:10:15  Main Para. Deploy    Main parachute deploys at 10,000 ft (3.0 km). Descent 
                                 rate slows to 30 ft/s (9.1 m/s)
T+00:10:20  Landing Bag Deploy   Landing Bag Deploys, dropping heat shield down 4 ft 
                                 (1.2 m).
T+00:10:20  Fuel Dump            Remaining hydrogen peroxide fuel automatically dumped.
T+00:15:30  Splashdown           Spacecraft lands in water about 300 mi (480 km) 
                                 downrange from launch site.
T+00:15:30  Rescue Aids Deploy   Rescue aid package deployed. The package includes 
                                 green dye marker, recovery radio beacon and whip 
                                 antenna.
```

<sup>Units are also converted into metric system for convenience, original mission communications transcript is available [here](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/MR04_TEC.PDF) (in PDF format).</sup>

Comment: Apollo displays were imperial, but the systems used metric and converted for the convenience of the crew